# Checking for mails

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, scripting, mail-command

I recently started using mails via UNIX.

I would like to create a script , that would write (every time I log in ) something like

> "The content of your mailbox has changed since last checkup"

or

> "The content of your mailbox is same since last checkup"

I read a documentation on `mail` and `mailx`

I came up with script

```
ls -l "var/mail/USER" | awk '{print $5}'
```

This basically print the size of the file. How can I create script that will check this number when I log in and compare it to the number I previously logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Not the literal answer to your question, but check the [mailcheck(1)](http://mailcheck.sourceforge.net/) utility. In addition to other existing more or less standard tools, it can check maildirs as well.

Comment: i want to write by myself , i shouldnt be that hard , but my knowledge of some things isnt that good.

Comment: @trolkura Well, if you configure your mail system to use maildir, it is rather simple: `ls -1 ~/Maildir/new |wc -l` :-)